# How to Split list of content after a certain amount of rendered elements

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to get a block to split content after so many entry's have been selected by the user in the backend of my website.

This is what is is supposed to look like
[image]

However at the moment I cannot get it to break off a second line. here is the code below to show how I am rendering my block along with an image of what is being rendered

```
function roomFacilitiesLists(){
$roomFacilitiesList1 = get_field ("facilities_list_1")  ; 
$roomFacilitiesList2 = get_field ("facilities_list_2")  ;
$roomFacilitiesList3 = get_field ("facilities_list_3") ;
$roomFacilitiesLeftSideImage = get_field ("room_facilities_left_side_image") ;
$roomFacilitysBackgroundImage = get_field ("room_facilitys_background_image") ; 
?>  
<div class="left-side-image-block-parent">
    <div class="left-sided-image">
        <img src="<?php echo $roomFacilitiesLeftSideImage['url']; ?>" ; />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="right-side-room-facilitys">
    <div class="room-facilities-lists" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $roomFacilitysBackgroundImage['url']; ?>)"> ;
</div>
<div class="main-lists-container">
    
    
<div class="column-1-list">
        
<?php
if( $roomFacilitiesList1 ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $roomFacilitiesList1 as $roomFacilitiesList1 ): ?>
            <div><?php echo $roomFacilitiesList1; ?></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
        
</div>  
    
    <div class="column-3-list columns-2">
        
<?php
if( $roomFacilitiesList3 ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $roomFacilitiesList3 as $roomFacilitiesList3 ): ?>
            <div><?php echo $roomFacilitiesList3; ?></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
        
</div>  
    
<div class="column-2-list">
        
<?php
if( $roomFacilitiesList2 ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $roomFacilitiesList2 as $roomFacilitiesList2 ): ?>
            <div><?php echo $roomFacilitiesList2; ?></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
        
</div>  
    
    

    

</div>

</div>
```

[image]

Now this makes up 3 columns of data however the other 2 are not the issue here is "columns-3" which is the data output causing the issues.

I have tried using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php as well as https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode but with no prevail any help here would be great.

Comment: Have you considered just using CSS in the browser to apply columns to the content?

Comment: @DavidThomas Due to the nature of the content I thought using display: grid; and grod-template-columns: 2fr 1fr ; 

would allow for better management of future content implementation

Comment: Sure, but whether you use grid, flex-box or multi-column layout is an implementation detail (and could work well, depending on your use and requirements). My point, though, is that if PHP is rendering a single list with all facilities, then you can use CSS to avoid having to split the list into various sub-lists and benefit from responsive design.

Comment: @DavidThomas so in your opinion how should I go about this a code example may help me understand your process a bit more.

Comment: My code example would depend on the code generated by the PHP, so can you first provide the relevant HTML that's sent to, and seen by, your browser? Basically copy & paste the relevant elements from the "view source."